# Does a user's personalized prediction data include all tags?

Tags: support, personal-data

I just heard about the [personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) that's being collected and decided to check it out. I downloaded my personal data, extracted the tags, and sorted in decreasing order. After seeing what I view the most, I'm questioning whether the data is taken over all time, or some window — perhaps one year.

It would surprise me if it's not windowed since my most viewed tag is for a language I've been using at work for the past 1 year, and for several years previous to that I developed in a different language which has a much lower count.

So simply put, does the tag data in my personalized prediction data account for all time, or is it limited to some window of time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We started maintaining Tag View data as of September 1, 2014. So that's the earliest possible information in your personalized prediction data.

If you've got a Stack Exchange account we'll maintain your data indefinitely, unless you tell us to turn it off via the Personalized Prediction Data page.

If you're anonymous (not logged in) we keep your data up to date as long as you visit once every six weeks. After six weeks of no visits it expires out of the system.